# Restangular getList() method not returning JSON

Tags: javascript, json, restangular

I have problem with geting a data from Restangular promise. I always get a promise instead of pure data in JSON.

This is response from my API

localhost:3000/api/meal

```
{
 "status": "success",
 "data": [
   {
     "meal_id": 4,
     "meal_type_id": 2,
     "description": "blahblah",
     "price": "3.50",
     "info": "120/120/20g",
     "restaurant_id": 2
   },
     ...
     ...
}
 ],
 "message": "Retrieved ALL meals"
}
```

This is my config method for extracting data from response

```
 RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
  var extractedData;
  // .. to look for getList operations
  if (operation === 'getList') {
    // .. and handle the data and meta data

  return data.data;

  } else {
    extractedData = data.data;
  }
  return extractedData;
});
```

This is how I am trying to get data from my API

```
  Restangular.all('meal').getList().then(function(meals) {
     $scope.menu = meals; //meals.plain() 
     console.log($scope.menu);
 });
```

but i always get this response

[image]
[image]

I need just JSON array from "data" field for using in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Sry guys, after hours of research and debuging I found bug in my backend API in one specific select. Now Express.js, pg-promise and application works correctly.